# Add legend in Seaborn combo line bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to add a legend to my seaborn bar + line chart, but only getting the error "No handles with labels found to put in legend." whatever I try. How to go about this?

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np    

dfGroup = pd.DataFrame({
        'Year': [1910, 1911, 1912, 1913, 1914, 1915, 1916, 1917, 1918, 1919, 1920],
        'Total Deaths': [0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        'Total Affected': [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 12, 13, 15]
        })
# Add 3-year rolling average
dfGroup['rolling_3years'] = dfGroup['Total Deaths'].rolling(3).mean().shift(0)
dfGroup = dfGroup.fillna(0)

# Make a smooth line from the 3-year rolling average
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline
X_Y_Spline = make_interp_spline(dfGroup['Year'], dfGroup['rolling_3years'])
 
# Returns evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.
X_ = np.linspace(dfGroup['Year'].min(), dfGroup['Year'].max(), 500)
Y_ = X_Y_Spline(X_)

# Plot the data
a4_dims = (15, 10)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=a4_dims)

ax1 = sns.barplot(x = "Year", y = "Total Deaths",
             data = dfGroup, color='#42b7bd')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2 = sns.lineplot(X_, Y_, marker='o')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seaborn's `barplot` uses categorical positions, internally numbered `0,1,2,...` both plots can be drawn on the same `ax`. This can be accomplished by recalculating the `x` values for the `lineplot`.

To obtain a legend, the `label=` keyword should be used. (Creating a legend on `twinx` axes is a bit more complicated and would involve creating custom handles.) Seaborn often automatically creates a legend.  If you want to change its appearance, you can call `ax1.legend(...)` with customization parameters.

Here is some example code:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

dfGroup = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year': [1910, 1911, 1912, 1913, 1914, 1915, 1916, 1917, 1918, 1919, 1920],
    'Total Deaths': [0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    'Total Affected': [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 12, 13, 15]
})
# Add 3-year rolling average
dfGroup['rolling_3years'] = dfGroup['Total Deaths'].rolling(3).mean().shift(0)
dfGroup = dfGroup.fillna(0)

# Make a smooth line from the 3-year rolling average
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

X_Y_Spline = make_interp_spline(dfGroup['Year'], dfGroup['rolling_3years'])

# Returns evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.
X_ = np.linspace(dfGroup['Year'].min(), dfGroup['Year'].max(), 500)
Y_ = X_Y_Spline(X_)

# Plot the data
a4_dims = (15, 10)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=a4_dims)
sns.barplot(x="Year", y="Total Deaths",
            data=dfGroup, color='#42b7bd', label='Barplot label', ax=ax1)
x_plot = np.linspace(0, len(dfGroup) - 1, len(X_))
sns.lineplot(x=x_plot, y=Y_, marker='o', label='LinePlot label', ax=ax1)
ax1.set_ylim(ymin=0) # let bars touch the bottom of the plot
ax1.margins(x=0.02) # less margins left and right
# ax1.legend(title='legend title') # optionally change the legend
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot with sns.lineplot and legend]

PS: If an `ax` is already created, it should be given as a parameter to seaborn's [axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) (so, `sns.barplot(..., ax=ax1)` instead of `ax1 = sns.barplot(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me: ax - the axes/subplot for bar, ax1 - for line

```
handles1, labels1 = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles2, labels2 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend((*handles1, *handles2), (labels1, labels2))
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this answer works, specifically how it differs from the accepted answer.